# JQuery : Finding the select elements inside the table row and listening to change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a table of rows which contains multiple select elements. I have given class to this select elements. I need to find the on change event of this select elements based on the class.

So i am using this to find the element

```
jQuery("table").on('click', 'tr', function () {
        jQuery(this).children().find('.select1').on('change', function () {
              //my action
        });
        //and same way the next select element
});
```

now with this im getting the on change event but the on change event is fired multiple time.
Initially once and then the count keeps on increasing. I need help with this coz i have been stuck for a very long time. Thanks

Answer:

I wanted to listen the change event of the select and on that add more element to the row. So now i am using delegate() to listen to the select change event and then getting the parent 
using jQuery(this).closest('tr'); to append other table data.

```
jQuery('table').on('click','select1',function(){
    //get the parent
    jQuery(this).closest('tr');
    //Do the rest
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for the `tr` click event, if the select elements are static then register the click handler directly

```
jQuery('table .select1').on('change', function () {
    //my action
});
```

if they are created dynamically then use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
jQuery('table').on('change', '.select1', function () {
    //my action
});
```

In your code every time you click on a tr a new change handler will get added to the `select1` element in that `tr` that is not what you wants, is it?

Comment: actually the thing is on select of 1st element i am populating the very next select element and appending one more  row to the table. So the select is not static.

Comment: @user3273621 then use event delegation model I gave

Comment: so its like a table has multiple select and also class select1. I need to find which one is changed.

Comment: ya i tried delegation but then again the event is called multiple times

Comment: @user3273621 this code should be executed only once.. probably on dom ready

Comment: @user3273621 `this` inside the handler will refer to the select element which was changed

Comment: to find the particular row and then find the class i am using the click event on the tr

Comment: @user3273621 sorry not sure what you are looking for